# Getting messages from specific email address swaps sentdatetime ordering

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api

In the Microsoft Graph, when I get my emails using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`, I get my emails fine. But when I want emails from a specific user (by adding `$filter=(from/emailAddress/address) eq 'some.email@domain.com'`), I get emails from like, last year. It's like the order just swaps if I add a filter for the sender of the email address.

Why did the order just swap?

I tried adding the `$filter` and `$orderby=sentdatetime desc` in the query, but it returns this error:

> The restriction or sort order is too complex for this operation.

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

> ?$filter=sentdatetime ne null and (from/emailAddress/address) eq 'some.email@domain.com'&$orderby=sentdatetime

But it returned this error:

> An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using this:

> ?filter=sentDateTime gt 1800-01-01T01:01:00.000Z and (from/emailAddress/address) eq 'some.email@domain.com'&$orderby=sentdatetime desc

Though it still doesn't explain why the order was swapped in the first place, if that's why it's showing old emails.